# My account page, don't show the complete "Registration form"

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

my account page of woocommerce, is normally split in two, left side for registration and right side for login.
The registration part contains only two fields: email and password. It's normal this view?
Beacause, i would like to see the entire registration form. So the form with name/surname/street/country etc..
I want customers to register immediately by entering all the data.

I ask if it is normal to only see email and password for registration, because the site was previously managed by another person, I wouldn't want them to use css to customize this form.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it shows like this, but if you want to add more options like "Name, Phone number, Email" option in the registration form, you have to follow these two simple tips:-

Step 1: Enable the Customer Registration Option
[image: Enable the Customer Registration Option]

Step 2: Add Custom Code in Functions.php File

```
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Phone', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['billing_phone']) ? esc_attr($_POST['billing_phone']) : ''; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="reg_billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="reg_billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="reg_billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="reg_billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', 'wooc_extra_register_fields' );
```

if you want to do this using plugins, then you should read this article "[How to Add Custom WooCommerce Registration Form Fields](https://medium.com/@jahidshah/how-to-add-custom-woocommerce-registration-form-fields-1bb420b7a54f)".